# How do I parse answers from AWS Mechanical Turk in Java?

Tags: java, xml, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

The `answer()` method for an `Assignment` returns a `String` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?><QuestionFormAnswers xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2005-10-01/QuestionFormAnswers.xsd"><Answer><QuestionIdentifier>blah</QuestionIdentifier><FreeText>toplevel</FreeText></Answer></QuestionFormAnswers>
```

How am I supposed to parse this to get the actual answers? I see in older versions of the API there's a `QuestionFormAnswers` type. This is also referenced in the documentation, which states:

> public String getAnswer()
>
> The Worker's answers submitted for the HIT contained in a QuestionFormAnswers document, if the Worker provides an answer. If the Worker does not provide any answers, Answer may contain a QuestionFormAnswers document, or Answer may be empty.
>
> Returns:
>
> The Worker's answers submitted for the HIT contained in a QuestionFormAnswers document, if the Worker provides an answer. If the Worker does not provide any answers, Answer may contain a QuestionFormAnswers document, or Answer may be empty.

But it actually returns a String and not a `QuestionFormAnswers`. How do I parse this string XML result? Can I just use any standard method of parsing XML documents?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be yes, you can use any standard XML parsing technique.

Here is what worked for me:

```
private static Map<String, String> parseXML(String answerXML) {
    try {
        List<String> identifierList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> answerList = new ArrayList<>();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(answerXML));
        Document document = null;
        document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList identifiers = null;
        try {
            identifiers = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//Answer/QuestionIdentifier", document,
                    XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < identifiers.getLength(); i++) {
            Node identifier = identifiers.item(i);
            String relation = identifier.getTextContent();
            identifierList.add(relation);
        }
        NodeList texts = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//Answer/FreeText", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < texts.getLength(); i++) {
            Node text = texts.item(i);
            String answer = text.getTextContent();
            answerList.add(answer);
        }
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (int k = 0; k < identifierList.size(); k++) {
            result.put(identifierList.get(k), answerList.get(k));
        }
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Failed to parse XML " + answerXML, e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This creates a map from the input ids to the answers.